# How do I add more rows to this autocomplete function which pulls from a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is my hardcoded data:

```
autocompleteList3 = {
'': ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
    'two': ['3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', 'test55'],
    'one': ['3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', 'test55'],
}
```

My import of a .csv file with data having the same number of items:

```
with open('boxes2.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        autocompleteList3[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3]]
```

First problem: I can't add more than three rows here... If I continue to row[4]], I get cut off. the ] key seems to limit me somehow. What's going on here? I need rows 1 through 18...

This is my auto complete function:

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, cList):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)                                 

        self.cList = cList
        self.Input_5.addItems(sorted(cList.keys())) 
        self.Input_5.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText2)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def onActivatedText2(self, text):
    self.Input_19.setText(self.cList[text][0])
    self.Input_29.setText(self.cList[text][1])
    self.Input_30.setText(self.cList[text][2])
    self.Input_18.setText(self.cList[text][3])
    self.Input_15.setText(self.cList[text][4])
    self.Input_14.setText(self.cList[text][5])
    self.Input_13.setText(self.cList[text][6])
    self.Input_25.setText(self.cList[text][7])
    self.Input_20.setText(self.cList[text][8])
    self.Input_21.setText(self.cList[text][9])
    self.Input_22.setText(self.cList[text][10])
    self.Input_24.setText(self.cList[text][11])
    self.Input_26.setText(self.cList[text][12])
    self.Input_28.setText(self.cList[text][13])
    self.Input_23.setText(self.cList[text][14])
    self.Input_27.setText(self.cList[text][15])
    self.Input_31.setText(self.cList[text][16])
    self.Input_32.setText(self.cList[text][17])
    self.Input_33.setText(self.cList[text][18])
```

So when I select two or one, 3332, 234234 etc fills all my inputs automatically. I can't get it working with the CSV file beyond three inputs. Actually, I don't even want to have hardcoded keys/pairs. If I can simply pull from the CSV file and have all 18 values autocomplete, that would be ideal. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

got it. So, my indexing was messed up:

```
with open('boxes2.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:
    autocompleteList3[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]]
```

I was able to add more rows after I ensured my .csv file did not contain empty cells.  Just one empty cell in row 3 crashed everything.